# Output 3 most recent posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if anyone new how to show the 3 most recent posts in Wordpress? Any help would be much appreciated.

How about just the post's thumbnail outputting 3 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

For example, on the homepage, you would normally see the latest 10 posts. If you want to show only 3 posts (and don't care about pagination), you can use query_posts() like so:

query_posts( 'posts_per_page=3' );

Hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

WordPress have an inbuilt function to get the recent posts.

```
wp_get_recent_posts( $args ) ;
```

`$args` is the arguments you need to pass. To get the three most recent published posts you can do it like :

```
$args = array('numberposts' => 3, 'post_status' => 'publish');
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args ) ;

print_r($recent_posts);
```

You can get more info on this link [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts)

Hope this helps you :)